# Filter Sharepoint list based on logged in User?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list called "My Task". In here we can assign task to particular user by HRUser. Once that perticular user logged in the My task list the list should be showed only that particular user's Task.So dont allow him to see other's Task history in that list. How can I do it.Please help me.

Comment: I dont think that is possible out of the box

Answer (score 3):

List Settings > Views > All Items ( or your view ) > Filter

Add a new filter:

'To create a view of only those items that you added, apply the filter Created By is equal to [Me]'

Comment: Thansk for your response. Let me know can we create custome view for that list using visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is to modify view and set the condition. You can compare Assigned To column with [Me] constant (the constant is mentioned in the hint text of the block). This is easy but not bullet-proof solution as user can change the view or use any other access to get other users' tasks.

The bullet-proof solution is to set up permissions of each task to assigned user. This can be done by event receiver (code solution) handling ItemUpdated event.

Comment: Thansk for your response. Let me know can we create custome view for that list using visual studio?

Comment: Yes. You can define the view with required condition in Visual Studio within the list definition. Here is the query part of view definition <Query><Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' LookupId='TRUE' />
        <Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value>
    </Eq>
</Where></Query>